# Manage personal OneDrive account with Azure

Tags: azure, onedrive

Is it possible to manage my personal consumer OneDrive account, tied to an E-Mail Account, like "happy@hotmail.com" with Azure? The one that is used with Windows 8/10 Desktop/Phone?
All I can see in the Azure Options is the possibility to create new storage accounts linked to new addresses like "account.azureservice.com" or similar.
Target: Writing an azure service that recognizes an incoming file on the OneDrive account from my phone/pc and processes that. So every app on the phone/pc uses the service automatically, without doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You do not create a storage account for linking your OneDrive account to your Azure services. Some Azure services provide some kind of adapters to link to OneDrive, DropBox etc.
From what you mentioned I think a Logic App would be a good fit. When you create one, you can create a trigger which fires for new files in one of your OneDrive folders. In order to to do that, you first have to give it permission to access your OneDrive account and then specify the folder to watch on - see screenshots below. Likewise, you can of course also create files in your OneDrive account.

[image: Sign in]

[image: Select folder]

There is even a template which shows how to copy new files from Dropbox to OneDrive

[image: Template for copying files from Dropbox to OneDrive]

Comment: Thanks, that seems to solve some part of the problem. Now I can move every incoming file to, lets say, google drive.

Comment: You can also add a processing stage which calls some function in azure functions to process your data.

Comment: Edit (after 5 Min limit): Thanks, that seems to solve some part of the problem. Now I can move every incoming file to, for example, Google Drive. But how can I modify the GET requests so that they return the content of Google Drive? I found this https://dev.onedrive.com/resources/item.htm, but don't know how to link it to OneDrive. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I must admit I do not fully get your comment. Are you talking about Google Drive or OneDrive?

Comment: The idea is to mirror the Google Drive content into OneDrive. Or of another cloud service, doesn't have to be specifically Google Drive. Think of it as a symbolic link of one directory onto another.

Comment: As it turns out there is even a template provided for copying new files from Dropbox to OneDrive - see the screenshot in the updated answer. If it is only triggered from time to time this should be OK, but if you syncing files all the time you may want to take a closer look at the costs :)

Comment: No, I saw that. What I don't want is to have actually any files in the OneDrive account, but rather act as a proxy for arbitrary other sources which have the actual files. Like a symbolic link from one directory pointing to another.